# How to create a jquery button that works with the result of php() loop & displays a message form when clicked?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm trying to create a button that brings out a hidden
message form & also hide the form after clicking the submit button 
using jquery. This button works with the results of
a php for() loop embeded in a while() loop that selects & arrange 
information from my database, so every result of the while() 
loop has the messagebutton below it.
Now, my problem is, after setting up all the loops and jquery codes,
everything works except that the message button works for all the
 results at thesame time when clicked which is not what i want.
I need the buttons to work separately in such a way that when the 
button under a loop result is clicked only 1 form slides down under 
the loop result and if another message button is clicked under another result, any open
 form closes and the new one opens.
In summary, I need the buttons to work independently for each loop result.
Here are the codes i used that are not giving me the desired result. Pls
help...

```
<?php
session_start();
include("databaselogin.inc");
mysql_select_db($database,$cxn);
$query="SELECT * from table1";
$result=mysql_query($query,$cxn) or die ("Couldn't execute query.". mysql_error());
$section=$_POST['section'];
?>
.
.
.
.
.
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$("div#show1").hide();
$("button#show2").click(function(){
  $("div#show1").toggle(500);
    });
    $("a#show3").click(function(){
  $("div#show1").hide(500);
    });
});
</script>



<?php
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$query1="SELECT * from table2 WHERE Email='$row[Email]'";
$result1=mysql_query($query1,$cxn) or die ("Couldn't execute query.". mysql_error());
$row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1);
for ($i=1; $i<=3; $i++)
    {
       if ($row['section1'."$i"]=="$section")
       {
        echo '<table height="130" width="220" border="1" style="border:thin"><tr height="104"><td width="60" valign="top" align="center">';
        echo '<center>';
        echo '<div style="line-height:80%">';
        echo '<img border="1" src="';
        echo $row['image'."$i"];
        echo '"width="80" alt="Your Name" height="78">';
        echo '</center>';
        echo '<font face="Comic Sans MS, Colonna MT, Juice ITC" size="2" color="#9900CC">';
        echo $row['section2'."$i"];
        echo '</font>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</td><td width="184" align="center" valign="top"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td bgcolor="#9900CC" width="174"><center><b><font face="Comic Sans MS, Colonna MT, Juice ITC" size="3" color="#ffffff">DESCRIPTION</font></b></center></td></tr><tr><td align="left" valign="top">';
        echo '<font face="Comic Sans MS, Colonna MT, Juice ITC" size="2" color="#9900CC">';
        echo $row['section3'."$i"];
        echo '</font>';
        echo '</td></tr></table><tr height="50" bgcolor="#9900CC"><td colspan="2" bgcolor="#ffffff">';
        echo '<div style="line-height:80%">';
        echo '<font face="Comic Sans MS, Colonna MT, Juice ITC" size="2" color="#9900CC">';
        echo $row1['port1'];
        echo '</font>';
        echo '<br />';
        echo '<font face="Comic Sans MS, Colonna MT, Juice ITC" size="1" color="#9900CC"><span style="white-space:pre">';
        echo $row1['port2'];
        echo '                                PRICE: ';
        echo $row['section4'."$i"];
        echo '</span>';
        echo '<br /><span style="white-space:pre">';
        echo $row1['port3'];
        echo '                                                 ';
        echo $row['section5'."$i"];
        echo '</span></font>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</td></tr>';
        echo '<tr height="10" bgcolor="#9900CC"><td colspan="2" bgcolor="#FDF4FD" style="border:none; line-height:30%" valign="top">';
        echo '<span style="white-space:pre"><button id="show2" style="border:none"><font face="Comic Sans MS, Colonna MT, Juice ITC" size="1" color="#9900CC">message</font></button>';
        echo '<font face="Comic Sans MS, Colonna MT, Juice ITC" size="1" color="#9900CC"> | </font>';
        echo '<font face="Comic Sans MS, Colonna MT, Juice ITC" size="1" color="#9900CC">comment</font></span>';
        echo '</td></tr></table>';
?>
          <!-- START DIV that contains the Private Message form -->
          <div id="show1">
          <table>
<form method="post" action="">
<font face="Comic Sans MS, Colonna MT, Juice ITC" size="2" color="#9900CC">Send a Message to <strong><?php echo $row1['port1']; ?></strong></font>
<tr><td align="right" width="80"><font face="Comic Sans MS, Colonna MT, Juice ITC" size="2" color="#9900CC">First Name:</font></td><td width="200"><input name="sender" type="text" maxlength="30" style="width:100%" /></td></tr>
<tr><td align="right" width="80"><font face="Comic Sans MS, Colonna MT, Juice ITC" size="2" color="#9900CC">Subject:</font></td><td width="200"><input name="pmSubject" id="pmSubject" type="text" maxlength="64" style="width:100%" /></td></tr>
<tr><td align="right" width="80" valign="top"><font face="Comic Sans MS, Colonna MT, Juice ITC" size="2" color="#9900CC">Message:</font></td><td width="200"><textarea name="pmTextArea" id="pmTextArea" rows="5" style="width:100%"></textarea></td></tr>
  <input name="pm_rec_name" id="pm_rec_name" type="hidden" value="<?php echo port4; ?>" />
  <span id="PMStatus" style="color:#F00;"></span>
  <br /><tr><td colspan="2"><span style="white-space:pre"><input name="pmSubmit" type="submit" value="Send" /><font face="Comic Sans MS, Colonna MT, Juice ITC" size="2" color="#9900CC"> or <a href="#" id="show3">Close</a></font></span>
<span id="pmFormProcessGif" style="display:none;"><img src="../loading.gif" width="28" height="10" alt="Loading" /></span></td></tr></form>
</table>
          </div>
          <!-- END DIV that contains the Private Message form -->
<?php
echo '<br />';  
       }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

okay I have not tested this, but what i did was put the javascript inside the loop and rename it each time as well as division, button and link. if you styled them, you will need to add a class and restyle them.

```
        <?php
    session_start();
    include("databaselogin.inc");
    mysql_select_db($database,$cxn);
    $query="SELECT * from table1";
    $result=mysql_query($query,$cxn) or die ("Couldn't execute query.". mysql_error());
    $section=$_POST['section'];
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc2.js"></script>
    <?php
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {

    $query1="SELECT * from table2 WHERE Email='$row[Email]'";
    $result1=mysql_query($query1,$cxn) or die ("Couldn't execute query.". mysql_error());
    $row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1);
    for ($i=1; $i<=3; $i++)
        {
$show1 = rand(1, 1000);
    $show2 = rand(1001, 2000);
    $show3 = rand(2001, 3000);
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("div#<?PHP echo $show1; ?>").hide();
    $("button#<?PHP echo $show2; ?>").click(function(){
      $("div#<?PHP echo $show1; ?>").toggle(500);
        });
        $("a#<?PHP echo $show3; ?>").click(function(){
      $("div#<?PHP echo $show1; ?>").hide(500);
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?PHP
           if ($row['section1'."$i"]=="$section")
           {
            echo '<table height="130" width="220" border="1" style="border:thin"><tr height="104"><td width="60" valign="top" align="center">';
            echo '<center>';
            echo '<div style="line-height:80%">';
            echo '<img border="1" src="';
            echo $row['image'."$i"];
            echo '"width="80" alt="Your Name" height="78">';
            echo '</center>';
            echo '<font face="Comic Sans MS, Colonna MT, Juice ITC" size="2" color="#9900CC">';
            echo $row['section2'."$i"];
            echo '</font>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</td><td width="184" align="center" valign="top"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td bgcolor="#9900CC" width="174"><center><b><font face="Comic Sans MS, Colonna MT, Juice ITC" size="3" color="#ffffff">DESCRIPTION</font></b></center></td></tr><tr><td align="left" valign="top">';
            echo '<font face="Comic Sans MS, Colonna MT, Juice ITC" size="2" color="#9900CC">';
            echo $row['section3'."$i"];
            echo '</font>';
            echo '</td></tr></table><tr height="50" bgcolor="#9900CC"><td colspan="2" bgcolor="#ffffff">';
            echo '<div style="line-height:80%">';
            echo '<font face="Comic Sans MS, Colonna MT, Juice ITC" size="2" color="#9900CC">';
            echo $row1['port1'];
            echo '</font>';
            echo '<br />';
            echo '<font face="Comic Sans MS, Colonna MT, Juice ITC" size="1" color="#9900CC"><span style="white-space:pre">';
            echo $row1['port2'];
            echo '                                PRICE: ';
            echo $row['section4'."$i"];
            echo '</span>';
            echo '<br /><span style="white-space:pre">';
            echo $row1['port3'];
            echo '                                                 ';
            echo $row['section5'."$i"];
            echo '</span></font>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</td></tr>';
            echo '<tr height="10" bgcolor="#9900CC"><td colspan="2" bgcolor="#FDF4FD" style="border:none; line-height:30%" valign="top">';
            echo '<span style="white-space:pre"><button id="'.$show2.'" style="border:none"><font face="Comic Sans MS, Colonna MT, Juice ITC" size="1" color="#9900CC">message</font></button>';
            echo '<font face="Comic Sans MS, Colonna MT, Juice ITC" size="1" color="#9900CC"> | </font>';
            echo '<font face="Comic Sans MS, Colonna MT, Juice ITC" size="1" color="#9900CC">comment</font></span>';
            echo '</td></tr></table>';
    ?>
              <!-- START DIV that contains the Private Message form -->
              <div id="<?PHP echo $show1; ?>">
              <table>
    <form method="post" action="">
    <font face="Comic Sans MS, Colonna MT, Juice ITC" size="2" color="#9900CC">Send a Message to <strong><?php echo $row1['port1']; ?></strong></font>
    <tr><td align="right" width="80"><font face="Comic Sans MS, Colonna MT, Juice ITC" size="2" color="#9900CC">First Name:</font></td><td width="200"><input name="sender" type="text" maxlength="30" style="width:100%" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td align="right" width="80"><font face="Comic Sans MS, Colonna MT, Juice ITC" size="2" color="#9900CC">Subject:</font></td><td width="200"><input name="pmSubject" id="pmSubject" type="text" maxlength="64" style="width:100%" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td align="right" width="80" valign="top"><font face="Comic Sans MS, Colonna MT, Juice ITC" size="2" color="#9900CC">Message:</font></td><td width="200"><textarea name="pmTextArea" id="pmTextArea" rows="5" style="width:100%"></textarea></td></tr>
      <input name="pm_rec_name" id="pm_rec_name" type="hidden" value="<?php echo port4; ?>" />
      <span id="PMStatus" style="color:#F00;"></span>
      <br /><tr><td colspan="2"><span style="white-space:pre"><input name="pmSubmit" type="submit" value="Send" /><font face="Comic Sans MS, Colonna MT, Juice ITC" size="2" color="#9900CC"> or <a href="#" id="<?PHP echo $show3; ?>">Close</a></font></span>
    <span id="pmFormProcessGif" style="display:none;"><img src="../loading.gif" width="28" height="10" alt="Loading" /></span></td></tr></form>
    </table>
              </div>

              <!-- END DIV that contains the Private Message form -->

    <?php
    echo '<br />';  
           }
        }
    }
    ?>
```